# Use of cellfun and save functions to export specific variables fails

Tags: matlab

I have a strange error. The following is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of my problem:

```
ba = 1;
bb = 2;
bc = 3;

whos 

% Get variable names
varnames = who('b*')

% Definition of the filename
filename = 'bVariables';

cellfun(@(x) display( x ), varnames);

cellfun(@(x) save( filename, x, '-append' ), varnames);
```

First I declare variables starting with letter `b`. Then I use the `who` command to get the variable names that start with letter `b` (assume that I don't know them before running the script). The names are returned as a cell array of strings (char vectors).

I then try to save each variable individually to the given filename with `save` defined as an anonymous function used by `cellfun`.

*Here is the output I get from the above MCV:*

```
varnames = 

    'ba'
    'bb'
    'bc'


x =

ba


x =

bb


x =

bc

Error using save
Variable 'ba' not found.

Error in @(x)save(filename,x,'-append')
```

This is really strange as the variables really do exist in workspace.

- Am I using `cellfun` wrong?
- Is it probably related to the use of an anonymous function and the visibility of variables?

Comment: I can reproduce your error with Matlab v2012 and no idea why. However, I see another issue in your cellfun while saving the variables. You use '-append' which "adds new variables to an existing file". In your case, if the file "bVariables" doesn't exist in the beginning, it will throw an error that the file doesn't exist. I would save the variables in the cell array 'varnames' using a loop without dealing with cellfun and save the first variable without '-append' argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it is because of the anonymous function and the scope of the variables. I can reproduce the error simply with eval function:

```
ba = 1;
bb = 2;
bc = 3;
whos
% Get variable names
varnames = who('b*')
cellfun(@(x) eval( x ), varnames);
```

However you can simply do it by doing this:

```
save(filename,varnames{:})
```

This outputs the content of the cell as a comma separated list handled by the save function. You can also add the `'-append'` at the end to make it append to that file: `save(filename,varnames{:},'-append')`

Comment: See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html#f4-71621 especially last paragraph of that section (the "Use only explicit variables..." part).